# Make a Rest Client in .NET Framework 4.0

Tags: .net, rest, curl, client

I am very new to .NET Framework especially 4.0 and have not found any article nor documentation regarding how to make a REST API request with .NET Framework. I know the request to the URL was made correctly as it generated a an access_token both in curl and also Python

[image]

Below is the one made in Python

[image]

The on above was used with the requests library from Python below is also an example of a curl request.

```html
curl --location --request POST 'https://****-****/sso/auth/v1/service' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=999999-llll-llll-llll-abcdghe' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=ssuper-integration-friendly-hml' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

However I have been trying all week to make a client REST API in .NET Framework 4.0 and have not been sucessful please help me!

Thanks!

Comment: If you haven't “found any article nor documentation regarding how to make a REST API request with .NET Framework”, there is a serious problem you're not telling us about. Simply typing your title in Google provided many promising articles; the first one is [ASP.NET Web APIs](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/aspnet/apis). Try the code in that article. If it doesn't do what you want, post the code you tried, explain what you wanted it to do. Tell us what happened.

Comment: @DourHighArch already figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
using System.Net;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        var app = builder.Build();

string url = "***********";
        string clientSecret = "*******";
        string clientId = "************";
        string grantType = "**********";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        string postData = $"client_secret={clientSecret}&client_id={clientId}&grant_type={grantType}";
        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; }; 
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(responseText);
        }
   
    }
}
```

I figured it out this is the correct way